# Analogue of Kolmogorov/Arnold superposition for general manifolds?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology, manifolds, universal-algebra

*Previously [asked and bountied at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4331298/superposition-dimension-a-la-kolmogorov-arnold) with slightly different language:*

Given a topological space $\mathcal{X}$, let $$\mathsf{Cl_C}(\mathcal{X})=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C(\mathcal{X}^n,\mathcal{X})$$ be the **[clone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(algebra)) of finite-arity continuous functions on $\mathcal{X}$** (where $\mathcal{X}^n$ is given the product topology). Motivated by the [Kolmogorov-Arnold superposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold_representation_theorem), let the **superposition number** of $\mathcal{X}$ be the minimal cardinality of a set of continuous functions $\mathfrak{F}\subseteq\mathsf{Cl_C}(\mathcal{X})$ such that the clone generated by $\mathfrak{F}\cup C(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{X})$ is all of $\mathsf{Cl_C}(\mathcal{X})$.

Some quick observations:

- Any space homeomorphic to its square trivially has superposition number $1$: there is no real distinction between single- and multi-variable continuous functions over such a space once we bring in an appropriate pairing function.
- The K/A theorem says that the superposition number of $[0,1]$ is $1$, witnessed by $\{+\}$.
- It is **not** clear to me that shifting attention to maps with codomain $[0,1]$ results in the same notion (I strongly suspect it doesn't), so e.g. [Ostrand's extension of the K/A theorem](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1965-71-04/S0002-9904-1965-11363-5/S0002-9904-1965-11363-5.pdf) doesn't seem relevant here.

I'm generally curious for any relevant information, but the following particular question seems interesting: is there, for each finite $n$, a "nice" topological space with superposition number $n$? Of course this is really a whole family of questions, one for each meaning of "nice."  Tentatively I think the most interesting case is likely to be the following:

> **Question**: Is there, for each finite $n$, a connected topological manifold *(with or without boundary, not necessarily compact)* with superposition number $n$?

I suspect that every topological manifold has superposition number $1$, by some not-too-complicated extension of K/A, but I don't immediately see how to show that.

Comment: What do you mean with a "clone"?

Comment: @Wojowu Clone in [the sense of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(algebra)) universal algebra. To get the clone generated by $\mathfrak{G}$, you add in all the projection functions and the close under composition. The set of finite-arity continuous functions constitutes a clone, but $\mathfrak{F}\cup C(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{X})$ will (usually) merely *generate* a clone. (I've added a link to the definition to my question.)